# Should there be delay defined between reading(USB0) and writing(USB1) the values in C?

Tags: c

I am an amateur and just exploring the possibilities of storing data. I want to read values from readport and write it in writeport using termios.h. I am saving the values in a file in between. I am storing the values in a an array and printing from them. When I am writing them the output is not a desired one.  Should there be a delay before write so that the values get stored in the array first.

```
unsigned char buf[500];
int s=0;
do 
{   
    int rdlen, wdlen;
    rdlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    wlen = write(fdwr, buf, sizeof(buf));
    s = s+1;
} while ( s<sizeof(buf) );
```

Comment: This is operating system specific. Please provide an [mre] in your question. For Linux, see [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: "the output is not a desired one" is not a problem description. What happens? Why is that wrong? What should it be instead?

Comment: You aren't using the lengths returned by read and write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of data you're writing doesn't match the amount of data you're reading. Perhaps you meant:

```
unsigned char buf[500];
int rdlen, wlen;

rdlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
wlen = write(fdwr, buf, rdlen);
```

Comment: A test on `rdlen` and `wlen` is missing. Both could be negative on failure.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, read *carefully* [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Be aware that GNU/Linux is [open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source): the kernel source code is on [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/) and you are allowed to download and study it.... You could be interested by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Your call to `write` is wrong. You don't want to write more bytes that you did read. And the call to `read` can fail. You need to handle such a failure.

You probably want to increment `s` by `wlen`

Take several days to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then study, for inspiration, on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) the source code of *several* Linux applications using `read` and `write`.

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C compiler, compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then read *carefully* the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and of its preprocessor [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). You also want to read the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and perhaps of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

Of course, read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and some [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/), and also [*what every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) then perhaps the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)

Read of course the wikipage on [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) and [usb-devices(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/usb-devices.1.html) and [lsusb(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsusb.8.html).

> Should there be a delay before write....

### This is obviously hardware specific.

Do you have a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) computer, or what? I heard that USB *does* require some delays about a few µs.

If a delay *is* needed, on Linux, see [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and consider using [usleep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) or [nanosleep(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), or code some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around e.g. [ppoll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). Of course, the precision of the delay is related to hardware devices (such as [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer)). See also [osdev](https://osdev.org/). See also [timerfd_create(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html).

PS. You probably need to spend a week in reading documentation and existing source code.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more. Because when I try to write I am getting lot of junk values written

Comment: Follow every hyperlink I mentionned